# Cracking an .aes encrypted file where portion of password is known

Tags: encryption, aes

I have a .aes file whose decryption password I thought I knew but which does not yield the decrypted version of the file.

I am 99.9% certain that the password I have (and which, in fact, I had written down and safely stored) is correct. The problem is that the .aes file was generated by a well-known open-source Bitcoin wallet software known as MultiBit which simply stopped working sometime in 2017, with many other users reporting similar problems.

I am told that Multibit may have incorrectly rendered some non alphanumeric characters of my password to whatever internal function it was using to generate the encrypted file. That means in practice that I could potentially crack my .aes file if I cycle through the permutations represented by the question marks in a password string that looks something like this:

i-AM-a-PASS?RD-with-3-UNKN?WN-charact?rs

So I guess my question is: is anyone aware of a regex-based brute-force approach that could be used for cracking .aes encryption passwords? The regex itself may need to employ both ? and * characters.

The amount of Bitcoin in the wallet was absolutely trivial, but with Musk's recent tweets sending Bitcoin to new highs I'm thinking I could buy a spanking new laptop if I can crack this.

Any suggestions most welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: John the Ripper supports Multibit and can handle all kinds of password brute force approaches. https://github.com/openwall/john. That said, depending on the bug, it may not be possible to just enter a different password and have it unlock. It depends on the nature of the key-derivation bug. If you have reason to believe that a brute force will work, I'd use John; just warning you that it's possible that won't be enough.

Comment: AES do not use passwords. AES uses binary keys. You need to figure out how they derive the keys from passwords ...